# Are there cases where 'new' is preferred to Spring Autowire

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Any reason to prefer using the new keyword? For example, say I have a class that will only be called once within another class. In that case, would it be preferable to use the new keyword. Or would Autowire be prefered and why?

For example, say I have code that would need to call only 1 of several other classes, depending on a condition. Also, the Autowired classes may or may not have other classes Autowired inside them.

```
class MyClass {

    @Autowire
    Obj1 obj1;

    @Autowire
    Obj2 obj2;

    @Autowire
    Obj3 obj3;

    public ResponseObj myMethod() {
        ResponseObj responseObj;

        if (some condition) {
            responseObj = obj1.someMethod();  //any reason to use 'new' here instead?
        } else if (some other condition) {
            responseObj = obj2.someOtherMethod();
        } else
            responseObj = obj3.anotherMethod();
        }

        return responseObj;

    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/

Comment: The [following](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/168300/when-not-to-use-spring-to-instantiate-a-bean) seems like a relevant and a good discussion:

Answer (score 1):

If a class doesn't have heavy dependencies (it's easy to construct) and you never need to swap out it's implementation (like to test its interaction with a client, even),  then of course it's fine to create objects using a constructor.

You wouldn't inject a an Integer or a BigDecimal into a class. You'd create them with new. You might do the same with a DTO (data transfer object) as well.

Same deal with a class that stored state in an array list. You'd normally create the list with new when the class was created. Injecting a list instance wouldn't provide any advantages and people reading your code would be surprised to see you using DI.

However, if you were returning a Json string from a method, you'd want to inject your object mapper into the class. Both for flexibility and to facilitate testing.

Also, anything you need to inject either needs to be created in the spring configuration file or as an annotation on a class. You want your spring config file to reflect your application structure and not be  littered with extraneous object declarations. If you're using annotations, you'll find it difficult to expose something like an array list :).

Remember, spring created objects so you don't have to, but you don't use it for everything. You'll learn as you write more code.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, the Autowired classes may or may not have other classes
>   Autowired inside them.

That is an important point. If you use `new Obj3()` then it won't be a Spring-managed bean and so you'll have to manually create and set all of `obj3`'s dependencies as well as its dependencies' dependencies. And so on. What if you wanted to change the implementation of a shared dependency a couple levels down the object graph? If you used `new`, then you'd have to manually search around your code and change all occurrences of `new Obj3()` to `new Obj3B()`, etc, and that kind of defeats the purpose of autowiring. If you're going to using autowiring, it's better to just use it all the way and avoid `new`.